# How do i exlude two columns from db table in the return LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Assume i have the following table structure for employees

```
id int
fName varchar
lname varchar
adresss varchar
country varchar
```

Assume i have created a list of `employees`. in my `LINQ` statement to return all the employees in that table, i want to `exclude` the columns `address` and `country`. Without manually writing the columns i need in the `select()` is there any other way to exclude those two columns so i can do a select like this

```
db.EMployees.Exclude("Address").Exclude("Country").where(x=>x.lname=="marcus").Select(d=>d);
```

Comment: Why do you want to exclude properties? And also, why do you not want to write out the columns?

Comment: @Vlad274 assume your table has 35 columns and in the return object i only need 30. so would you exclude 4 or would you write 30 columns manually in the select block?

Comment: I wouldn't exclude columns at all. An entity is meant to represent a whole record, it's odd to say "I want this thing that is defined to represent a whole record to only be partially populated".

Comment: @Vlad274 assume entity has 35 cols but from it for my operation i need 30

Comment: EF is not designed for what you want. You're not working with an Entity, you're just working with data. And frankly, given that Intellisense exists, I can't see why typing things out once would be a problem?

Comment: @Vlad274 its about time, if i have to access data through json object i have to repeat the 30 cols again

Comment: I was just about to post the same answer as octavioccl. If your goal is not to expose sensitive data, there are other techniques. Create a viewmodel and use ProjectTo. https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/11/efficient-querying-with-linq-automapper-and-future-queries/

Comment: Or simply have protected properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that unless you project your query to get the result you are expecting:

```
public class EmployeesDTO
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string fName {get;set;}
   //the rest
}

var query= db.EMployees.Where(x=>x.lname=="marcus")
                       .Select(d=>new EmployeesDTO{Id=d.Id, fName=d.Name,...});
```

But a better idea is use Automapper to do the big select for you using [`ProjectTo`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) extension method:

```
var query= db.EMployees.Where(x=>x.lname=="marcus").ProjectTo<EmployeesDTO>();
```

Comment: thanks mate, i thought there is shortcut seeems like  i have to write the columns to a helper class anyway : )

Comment: you're welcome. That's right, but at least with the last variant you can avoid to write a `select` with all the columns every time that you need to consult your data ;)